# Can I add examples/citations to another person's answer?

Tags: discussion, support

Recently I was asking a question on the Stack Exchange network and received a very brief description of how to handle my issue.

Unfortunately the answer didn't have any citations or examples. As such, I took the liberty of modifying the author's post to include citations and an example which did exactly what the author had said.

In my mind I was "clarifying the meaning without changing it", "adding related resources or links", "[Making posts easier to understand, which helps both readers and the original poster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120583/157297)". Was I wrong?

Based on additional discussion I was told to add the additional information to the comments, but this seems to act opposite to "[Adding additional information only found in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120583/157297)". When I bring up these well defined suggestions for what edit's are for, the users do not answer clearly what I could've done better outside of creating a duplicate answer with my additional information.

Please clearly define when links/resources should be added to an existing answer versus when a duplicate answer should be created.

Comment: This question does not link to the post in question, as such it will be hard to give relevant feedback.

Comment: @StephenRauch which are not accepted do not appear in the revision history as such I'm unable to link to the rejected revision.

Comment: It seems that at least a few people have followed me here from a much more controversial post.  Please remember that this is a separate post.

Comment: Sure you can. Here it is: [stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20302919](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20302919)

Comment: @Colton, please understand, I did not "follow" you here. I, and others, hang out in more than one place...

Comment: @n8te thanks.  Is there a link somewhere or do I just need to remember to change the url?

Comment: You can see your actions here: [stackoverflow.com/users/453439/colton?tab=activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453439/colton?tab=activity). Just click on the "rejected edit" part.

Comment: @n8te, thank you for that link, I hadn't seen it previously as I had the `sort` set incorrectly.

Comment: Also: *[Edit correcting wrong information in original answer and adding example code has been rolled back because “it changed too much in the original post”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135874)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen thanks!  From the second link, there appears to be unanimous favor of doing so (though I'm not an [established user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)).  The first link appears to be saying that after 2000 rep it's fine but before that `suggested edits` it's unacceptable.  Kate (also the first link) appears to be saying she would reject due to unwillingness to review the content based purely on the size.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for the links, they were quite helpful, though subjectivity is somewhat frustrating when dealing with moderation at the very least I feel that my edits were valid but perhaps didn't satisfy the reviewers based on having an insufficient edit message.