# How my answer has changed hand

Tags: discussion, answers, suggested-edits, comment-replies

I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15025497/2096399).

After I posted, I saw, it seems answered by another user.
When I edited my edited post, someone commented this "@OgunAcik Please do not modify another users post by adding additional details, instead use a comment to point these additional details, so the OP can determine whether or not to update his post (if he agrees) – Veger"
and removed the part that I added.

How can it be? Is there a rule that I don't know?

Comment: I ***highly*** doubt that an answer of you was by accident assigned to another user. What most likely happened here is that your answer got deleted.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby There are no deleted answers on that question

Comment: See this related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145559/is-it-appropriate-to-edit-best-answers-solution-with-improvement-or-add-another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was the one who rolled back your edit.

My motivation was because it was an invalid edit, an edit made by someone who did not write the post which should have been a comment instead; you should propose changes like these to the owner of a post via comments (once you have gained 50 reputation).

Comment: You are completely right but like i said, i thinked it was my post and tried to edit. I don't know how it did. Anyway, I'm newbie and will get used to this. Thank you all.

Comment: @OgunAcik You'll get the hang of it :) Actually, the edit shouldn't have been approved in the first place, but that's just me.

Comment: It has been approved because it was my post :) by the way, sorry for my non-fluent English.

Comment: @OgunAcik But it's not, as you can see from the [edit suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1578595); author on the left, proposer (you) on the right ... not the same fella :)

Comment: OgunAcik's edit was to add a complement to the answer, not to propose a different solution. Assuming the proposed addition is correct (I don't know PHP so I can't tell), this suggested edit was reasonable. It also works as a comment, so I would recommend posting it as a comment, but it is not an invalid edit.

Comment: @Gilles It didn't answer my comment on locale awareness, which came closest to being related to this addition.

Answer (score 8):

You didn't answer that question. You [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1578595) to an already existing answer.

Comment: Yes, I did. But before doing this, I filled the form. Writed "Try this:", paste my code "echo date("m/d/Y - H:i");" and posted and saw it was posted another one. I didn't understand anything. I think, We posted with my friend at the same time and mine was not accepted. :)